# What is the hardware requirements to install Bugzilla?

Tags: bugzilla

Can anyone advise on hardware requirements like required disk space, memory and cpu requirements, and system configuration requirements such as the necessary user credentials? I will be installing this on a solaris server.

Comment: It's tough to answer this as is noted by the lack of official documentation. It really depends on the type and size of install you're looking to do

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found an answer, not for Solaris, but perhaps because it is about hardware and from experienced users, it can help you...

[mozilla.support.bugzilla › Hardware Configuration](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/mozilla.support.bugzilla/uef_4Gs3mSw)

They talk something about a modest HW config:

> a machine with 256MB RAM, and a PI 200MHz processor will run
>   Bugzilla at a decent speed for a small use instance